# problem with receiving structure with nrf24l01 using stm32

Tags: stm32, arm, nrf24l01

I am sending a structure that contains three float values and a uint64_t using stm32f103RE and nrf24l01 and receiving it via an stm32f103C8. the problem that I have is that the uint64_t is received correctly but the float values are received as zeros. the float values that I'm talking about are coordinate values that I'm getting from sim808. I can't share my whole code because it's too long but I can show the related parts of the code.
the transmitter code is as follows:

```
struct MyData 
{
  uint64_t car_id;
  float latitude_t;
  float longitude_t;
  float speed_t;
};

float latitude,longitude,speed;
int main()
while (1)
{
if (NRF24_write(&nrf_data,32))
    
            {      
                usart_sendstring("transmitted successfully");
            
            }
            HAL_Delay(1000);
}
```

the receiver code is as follows :

```
   float latitude;
    float longitude;
    float speed;
    uint64_t car_id;
    
    struct MyData 
    {
      uint64_t car_id;
      float latitude_t;
      float longitude_t;
      float speed_t;
    };
    int main()
            while(1)
            {
                    struct MyData nrf_data;
                    if (NRF24_available())
                    {
                            NRF24_read(&nrf_data,24);
                            char str[50];
                            char str2[50];
                            latitude=nrf_data.latitude_t;
                            longitude=nrf_data.longitude_t;
                            speed=nrf_data.speed_t;
                            car_id=nrf_data.car_id;     
                            sprintf(str2,"car code :%llu \n https://maps.google.com/? 
                            q=%.6f,%.6f",car_id,latitude,longitude);
                            Send_SMS(str2);
                    }
            }
```

what might be the problem here?

Comment: You seem to assume a certain struct size, but have you validated it? What does sizeof(struct MyData) tell you?

Comment: NRF24_write(&nrf_data,**32**) and NRF24_read(&nrf_data,**24**) seem strange, while the struct should have 20 bytes. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: @Justme  i used the sizeof  and printf with dev c++ and sizeof(struct MyData) evaluates to 24 bytes

Comment: @devnull 32 is the maximum payload length and 24 is the value of sizeof(struct MyData)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem I had was in other parts of my code and I fixed it now it works fine. the structure part was clean so I leave it here if anyone wants to use it.